# Returning to a specific tab when closing a tab - JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to create a new tab that gives some extra info when the user clicks on any item in a ListView. I managed to dynamically add new tabs and close them. I've also managed to switch to the newly created tab . So the new tab pops up and I can automatically see it. But I couldn't find a way to return to my original tab when the extra info tab is closed. It automatically returns to the tab before to it. Created tab is the fourth tab, when I close it, it goes back to the third tab, but I want it to go to the second tab. Is there any way to fix this. I don't use an FXML file.

Comment: When a tab closes, `TabPane` looks for the nearest non-disabled tab and sets it as the selected tab. This default mechanism is implemented inside `TabPaneSelectionModel`,  in order to change it, you have to create your own `SingleSelectionModel<Tab>`.

Comment: The other option is to listen for the tab closing and then manually select the tab you want.

Comment: @Slaw How can I do that? I don't know much about listeners. I tried this but didn't work: `artistDetailTab.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
                    mainScreenTabPane.getSelectionModel().select(albumsTab);
                });`

Comment: `tab.setOnClosed(e -> tp.getSelectionModel().select(otherTab))`

Comment: Though a slight problem with that is the handler will execute even if the tab wasn't selected when closed. You could configure the tab pane to only allow selected tabs to be closed, however.

Comment: @Slaw It worked, thanks. I had already done that to make my main tabs stay on the screen.